# Finding the difference between two datetimes in Months

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

Is this the right way to find the difference between two `datetime`s in terms of months as I find that the `months_to_maturity` column of my dataframe `df` remains the same before and after I find the difference. The code I use is below:

```
todays_date = datetime.date.today()
#Converting to datetime
datenow = datetime.datetime.combine(todays_date, datetime.datetime.min.time()) 

# Function to find the difference in months between the two datetime objects
def monthdelta(d1, d2):
    delta = 0
    while True:
        mdays = monthrange(d1.year, d1.month)[1]
        d1 += timedelta(days=mdays)
        if d1 <= d2:
            delta += 1
            else:
                break
    return delta 

# Re-assiging months_to_maturity in df with the difference between the two datetimes
for (i,row) in df.iterrows():
    row['months_to_maturity'] = monthdelta(datenow, datetime.datetime.strptime(row['maturity_dt'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

How about a custom function?

```
from datetime import datetime

def month_delta(d0, d1):
    dy = d1.year - d0.year
    dm = d1.month - d0.month
    return dm + (dy*12)
```

Note: it will take account only of fully finished months (without rounding up or down of the incomplete months).

Answer (score 0):

I think months are not a valid property of `datetime` because they not a standard unit of measurement (they can take as many as 4 different values). But days are, so we can compute the difference between two dates in days, and then divide it by the *average* number of days in a month, like this:

```py
def months_delta_exact(dt_start, 
                       dt_end, 
                       days_in_avg_month=30.437, 
                       use_fractions=True):

    dt_months_delta = (dt_end - dt_start).days / days_in_avg_month

    if not use_fractions:
        dt_months_delta = round(dt_months_delta) 
    
    return dt_months_delta


dt_start = datetime.strptime("2022/08/31", "%Y/%m/%d")
dt_end = datetime.strptime("2023/10/16", "%Y/%m/%d")
months_delta_exact(dt_start, dt_end, use_fractions=False)
>>> 14

dt_start = datetime.strptime("2022/08/31", "%Y/%m/%d")
dt_end = datetime.strptime("2023/10/15", "%Y/%m/%d")
months_delta_exact(dt_start, dt_end, use_fractions=False)
>>> 13
```